# jQuery/Angular 4: smooth transitions between images inside an array

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I'm building this slideshow in a component. It's pretty straight forward; I have the images inside an array and its index goes back and forth according to a timeout interval. The issue is that there is no transition; the image only gets replaced. I'm trying to figure out a solution with this code, But I don't know if its possible. Any ideas? (actually this is more like a jQuery thing). The code:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html'

})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  imgs:string[];
  imgindex:number;
  image:string;

  constructor() { 
    this.slideShow();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  slideShow(){
   this.imgs=["https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/fe/3c/61/fe3c61a811ad7aa24c7fcd8ff8586436--vampire-masquerade-vampire-art.jpg","http://www.themadcatlady.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/2013-11-0212.15.22.jpg","http://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Black-Cat-Pictures-12.jpg",
    "http://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Black-Cat-Pictures-12.jpg"];
   this.imgindex = 0;     
   this.image= $("#image");

         setInterval(function(){  
           this.imgindex++; 
            if (this.imgindex > (this.imgs.length - 1)) { 
          this.imgindex = 0; 
      }; 

    $('#image').attr('src', this.imgs[this.imgindex]); 

    }, 3000);

  }

}
```

Comment: you can go for existing caurosel

Comment: well, yes, actually i'm using bootsrap and there are plenty of pluggins out there, but i wonder if it can get it done this way, thanks